# How come my Java program goes faster when I execute a number of parallel threads superior to Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, processor

I have done some research on how to execute parallel threads in Java.
I have found an easy solution, which is to use `ExecutorService` class.
It is basically used by calling the following:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Each thread executes a simple task, such as a `System.out.println()`.

I have been told that `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns the number of processors, which is basically the number of execution engines capable of running your code, physically distinct or logical processors, if using hyper-threading.

However, when I use the following line instead:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*2);
```

my program actually goes a lot faster (even though I haven't calculated the exact running time, simply observing the obvious change in speed).

How is this possible? Also, if I multiply the number by three, it speeds up even more, even though the speed stops increasing with higher factors.

My computer is a MacBook Pro running on Yosemite, with a 2,2 GHz Intel Core i7 processor.

Comment: Does any of your threads do I/O?  Are any other processes running on the machine?

Comment: What is with this trend of writing JAVA in ALL CAPS? It's "Java".

Answer (score 1):

The simple task (calling `System.out.println()`) involves interacting with the outside world, and it may be blocked waiting for (say) the display device or a disk to respond.

A task could also be synchronizing with other tasks, and could have to wait for activity on another thread to do something, or wait on updates to shared variables.

The "number of threads ~= number of cores" rule is just a rule of thumb.  It is only predictive if the threads are truly independent of each other and external influences.  For a real world multi-threaded application, you need to tune the number of threads for the application, the platform and the problem if your aim is to maximize performance.

Answer (score 1):

Running with more worker threads than there are available processors is like having more than six players suited up for a hockey game.  If one player needs to leave the ice, there's another ready to leave the bench and take his place.

That's why I asked if any of your threads do I/O.  Doing I/O will block a thread until the I/O operation completes.  If you have more workers than there are available processors, then when one thread drops out to wait for I/O, another will be ready to take its place and continue using the CPU.  You'll get better utilization of the available cycles that way.

Don't forget that paging is I/O too.

I also asked whether there were any other processes running on the machine.  Desktop operating systems schedule threads according to some notion of "fairness".  I don't know what "fairness" means on Mac OS, but if it means that the OS tries to give each *thread* a fair share of CPU time (as opposed to giving each *process* a fair share), then a program that has more threads will get a larger share than a program that has fewer threads.  This will only matter if there are other programs that are actually using CPU.

Answer (score -1):

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);
```

creates a fixed pool of threads with the input number. More threads gives better performance in some scenarios depending the task performed by the threads.

In the following statements

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*2);
```

You are just using the number of cpu as a multiple but you are not actually explicitly involving the available cpus. Its only the thread number which is making the difference.